# If unspecified, what is the default value for MessageStorage in a Notes Person document?

Tags: messageformat

I'm having issues figuring out where it's grabbing the default value. I tried changing the message format field under the Mail tab in the Location document, but that didn't change the default message format when making person docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value is `"1"`, which in the English-language client has a display value of "Mime Format". Note that this value only applies to messages sent directly to the internet, and that's based on the recipient address (either what you entered or the translation after your local address lookup is completed). I don't get the connection to the Person document at all; the MailSystem field on the Advanced tab is entirely optional (and doesn't do much in any case). What matters on send is the resolved recipient address -- if you send to an internet address and have MIME Format ("1") selected on the location document, CD-to-MIME conversion is done in the client before send. If the address is a Notes address, then even if that resolves to an internet address in the Domino Directory, the message leaves your client in Notes Rich Text (CD) format.